# Shopify Python API Request ISO 8601 Fomat

Tags: python, json, shopify

The Shopify API reference says:

> **updated_at_min**
>   Show products last updated after date (**format: 2014-04-25T16:15:47-04:00**)

If I have a datetime object when making an API call, do I need to convert the datetime to a *string* of ISO 8601 format prior to making the request?

i.e. do I need to do this?

```
min_date = timezone.now()
shopify.Product.count(created_at_min = str(min_data.isoformat()))
```

My request would look like this then:

```
https://[store-url].myshopify.com/admin/products/count.json?updated_at_min=2017-01-29T14%3A43%3A27-05%3A00
```

Versus this (if I pass the ***unformatted*** datetime object in):

```
https://[store-url].myshopify.com/admin/products/count.json?updated_at_min=2016-12-10+14%3A43%3A27-05%3A00
```

*(If so, why doesn't the Shopify Python API handle this conversion automatically, seems kind of silly?)*

Comment: I haven't used that but if so, it may make sense to open an issue with the Shopify Python library if you think it should handle this already.

Comment: Thanks, I just created this: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api/issues/175

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(From a response to my issue on the Shopify Python repo): The Shopify API actually does accept several date formats, but it's always safest to use the format that is documented in the API documentation (ISO 8601), as this is guaranteed to continue working in the future.

The current Shopify Python module does not currently handle date formatting, because the bulk of the functionality of the library is for wrapping HTTP requests using pyactiveresource - it is largely a port of https://github.com/shopify/shopify_api and hasn't been extended to do this.